# Binding dataframes with different column names by row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I imported this excel sheet as a list of dataframes. I want to merge the list into one dataframe. `bind_rows()` allow me to easily add together the dataframes, but the issue is that I have a variable/column that has different names in each dataframe. `bind_row()` will by default create two separate columns, with empty values for the data from the other data frames. How can I join these columns?

Sample code:

```r
# Sample dataframes
df1 <- tibble(A = c(1,2,3),
              B = c("X","Y","Z"),
              C = c(T,F,F)
                  )
df2 <- tibble(A = c(3,4,5),
              B = c("U","V","W"),
              D = c(T,T,F)
)

# List of dataframes
my_ls <- list(df1, df2)
my_ls
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      A B     C    
  <dbl> <chr> <lgl>
1     1 X     TRUE 
2     2 Y     FALSE
3     3 Z     FALSE

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      A B     D    
  <dbl> <chr> <lgl>
1     3 U     TRUE 
2     4 V     TRUE 
3     5 W     FALSE

# Creating joined dataframe:
my_df <- bind_rows(my_ls)
my_df
# Current outcome: A tibble: 6 x 4
      A B     C     D    
  <dbl> <chr> <lgl> <lgl>
1     1 X     TRUE  NA   
2     2 Y     FALSE NA   
3     3 Z     FALSE NA   
4     3 U     NA    TRUE 
5     4 V     NA    TRUE 
6     5 W     NA    FALSE
```

The desired outcome:

```r
# Desired outcome: A tibble: 6 x 3
      A B     C         
  <dbl> <chr> <lgl> 
1     1 X     TRUE    
2     2 Y     FALSE    
3     3 Z     FALSE    
4     3 U     TRUE 
5     4 V     TRUE 
6     5 W     FALSE
```

Currently, I've been using `mutate()` with `case_when()`, where I check which column is not empty (`!is.na()`). This works, but I can't help but think there must be an easier way.

```r
# Example using mutate
my_df <- my_df %>% 
  mutate(
    C = case_when(is.na(C)  & !is.na(D) ~ D,
                  !is.na(C) & is.na(D)  ~ C,
                  # The lines below may be a bit redundant for my purpose, since the dataframes either have the C or D variable.
                  !is.na(C) & !is.na(D) ~ C, # Better would be to return that variable has overlapping information
                  is.na(C)  & is.na(D)  ~ NA
                 )
         ) %>%
        select(-D)
my_df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
      A B     C    
  <dbl> <chr> <lgl>
1     1 X     TRUE 
2     2 Y     FALSE
3     3 Z     FALSE
4     3 U     TRUE 
5     4 V     TRUE 
6     5 W     FALSE
```

Comment: Wont's this work? names(df2) = names(df1)
df1 %>% bind_rows(df2)
i.e. changing col names of second dataframe and then binding rows?

Comment: Could be. That would require that the dataframes' names appear in the same order, wouldn't it? I should perhaps have clarified this better. In reality, I have multiple dataframes, with either variable C or D, and not necessarily ordered similarly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `bind_rows` and then select non-NA value using `coalesce` :

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(my_ls) %>% mutate(C = coalesce(C, D)) %>% select(A:C)

#      A  B     C    
#  <dbl> <chr> <lgl>
#1     1 X     TRUE 
#2     2 Y     FALSE
#3     3 Z     FALSE
#4     3 U     TRUE 
#5     4 V     TRUE 
#6     5 W     FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer is simple and works well with my already written code. Perhaps better to drop `D` (`select(-D)`), rather than selecting for `A:C`, as this will remove the redundant variable regardless of its position among the other variables..

Answer (score 1):

Apologize for breaking out of the tidyverse for a quick answer

```
expl <- read.table(text= " A B     C     D    
1     1 X     TRUE  NA   
2     2 Y     FALSE NA   
3     3 Z     FALSE NA   
4     3 U     NA    TRUE 
5     4 V     NA    TRUE 
6     5 W     NA    FALSE")

expl$E <- ifelse(is.na(expl$C), expl$D, expl$C)

print(expl)
```

or maybe

```
expl[,c("C", "D")] %>% rowMeans(na.rm = TRUE) %>% as.logical()
```

EDIT: Translated the latter to tidy:

```
expl %>% select("C", "D") %>% rowMeans(na.rm = TRUE) %>% as.logical()
```

**EDIT after first comment:**

If you want more control you should probably write the things you want to do in each case in a function similar to the following example:

```
library(magrittr)

expl <- read.table(text= " A B     C     D    
1     1 X     TRUE  NA   
2     2 Y     FALSE NA   
3     3 Z     FALSE NA   
4     3 U     NA    TRUE 
5     4 V     NA    TRUE 
6     5 W     NA    FALSE
7     7 I     NA    NA
8     9 J     TRUE  TRUE")

myfun <- function(a, b){
  if(is.na(a) & is.na(b)) 
     return(NA)
  if(!is.na(a) & !is.na(b)) {
    warning("too much information, a and b set!")
    return(NaN)
  }
  return(max(a, b, na.rm=TRUE))
}

myfun = Vectorize(myfun)

myfun(expl$C, expl$D) %>% as.logical()
```

Comment: Your upper solution seem to be what I want. Hypothetically, for a more idiot-proof solution. Say there's information in both columns, and I would like to check that there is no information lost before I transfer the information and remove column D?

Comment: I added a solution that gives you very fine grained control: Just write a function what exactly should happen in which case, vectorize that and the rest is easy. HTH

Comment: Could you elaborate on what vectorization does? Do I understand the code correctly, that this would only work on logical input? I'd prefer a more of a universal one-liner. But a using conditionals is a great way for testing for overlapping information.

Comment: It is only the last step that transforms the result to logical, because that was the question. If you remove that it works for all numeric. For characters you would need to change the max part sensibly. Vectorization is a smart way to make a function that accepts two values accept two vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Following the comment by @KarthikS you can rename your columns before binding. My approach using `rename_with` does not require the columns to be in a specific order. To illusrate this I used somewhat different example dataframes:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

d1 <- data.frame(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3)
d2 <- data.frame(A = 4, B = 5, D = 6)
d3 <- data.frame(D = 7, A = 8, B = 9)

d <- list(d1, d2, d3)

map(d, ~ rename_with(.x, ~ "C", matches("^D$"))) %>% 
  bind_rows()
#>   A B C
#> 1 1 2 3
#> 2 4 5 6
#> 3 8 9 7
```

And now four your dataset:

```r
d <- list(df1, df2)
map(d, ~ rename_with(.x, ~ "C", matches("^D$"))) %>% 
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>       A B     C    
#>   <dbl> <chr> <lgl>
#> 1     1 X     TRUE 
#> 2     2 Y     FALSE
#> 3     3 Z     FALSE
#> 4     3 U     TRUE 
#> 5     4 V     TRUE 
#> 6     5 W     FALSE
```

And if we add an addtional one with a different order:

```r
df3 <- tibble(D = c(T,T,F),
              A = c(7,8,9),
              B = c("A","B","C"))

d <- list(df1, df2, df3)
map(d, ~ rename_with(.x, ~ "C", matches("^D$"))) %>% 
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>       A B     C    
#>   <dbl> <chr> <lgl>
#> 1     1 X     TRUE 
#> 2     2 Y     FALSE
#> 3     3 Z     FALSE
#> 4     3 U     TRUE 
#> 5     4 V     TRUE 
#> 6     5 W     FALSE
#> 7     7 A     TRUE 
#> 8     8 B     TRUE 
#> 9     9 C     FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is a short a short and simple solution. Could you elaborate what "^" and "$" in "^D$" do? Could a check for the presence of both "C" and "D" columns in a dataframe before renaming be implemented?

Comment: The "^" marks the start of a string, while the "$" marks the end. Hence the pattern `"^D$"` matches only columns named exactly "D".